# how to call interface method in view model of fragment class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, viewmodel

I have an `Activity` which is called `Homeactivity` and I have a fragment `Notification` and their `ViewModel` class, I want to update notification count from fragment's `ViewModel` and I declared that interface outside the notification `ViewModel` and I'm unable to call the method of that interface in Kotlin

```
class NotificationsViewModel(val notificationsActivity: HomeActivity) : 
          BaseObservable() {  


 //somewhere i want to update count which is in homeactivity

    } 
  interface NotifyCount {
    fun notifyNotificationCount(count: String)

}
```

My fragment class is given below

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {
private var notificationsBinding: NotificationsActivityBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    notificationsBinding=  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.notifications_activity,container,false)
    notificationsBinding!!.viewModel= NotificationsViewModel(activity!! as HomeActivity)
    return notificationsBinding!!.root
}

}
```

I just want to call method `notifyNotificationCount` in `ViewModel` so that I will update my count from `HomeActivity` by overriding the `NotifyCount`

how can I call the method `notifyNotificationCount` in 
viewModel` class?

Comment: Have your read this? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: Also, this: https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c

Comment: @AndreArtus i will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MutableLiveData` in your ViewModel class and observe the value of notification count, whenever the value of notification count changed it will inform to observing the class.